# display content using outter scroll not inner scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll

This is my website: http://goo.gl/takPK There are two scrolls on the page: one is white box scroll, another is main webpage scroll. I tried to set whitebox to overflow:hidden with no luck. The content will show up just half data, not the whole data.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: If i understand your question good. You want to get rid of the inside scroll?

Comment: yes, could you help me to fix it?

Comment: Look at the answer, that should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the fixed height in the div element.

`<div class="span8" id="home-copy" style="height: 775.8px; height: auto;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(128, 128, 128); padding-top: 70px; ooverflow: auto;verflow: auto;"></div>`

or change it in the html to `auto` OR

in the css `#home-copy{height:auto !important;}` OR

in the css `.span8{height:auto !important;}`